# distribution of distance

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

If a ball is kicked with a mean of 10 feet and standard deviation of 1 foot, then kicked back towards the starting point with a mean of 5 feet and standard deviation of 0.5 feet, what is the distribution of the distance from the initial and final position?

Comment: Means add.  Variances add.

Comment: Beth, I'm pretty sure you'd want the "probability-distribution" tag instead of "distribution-theory" tag, so I edited the tags. The latter refers to generalized functions, and is not really about the probability-theory sense of the word.

Answer (score 2):

$${\cal N}(\mu_1 - \mu_2, \sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2)$$